# AWS spark jobs monitoring tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, monitoring

I have a AWS cluster with 12 nodes, 8 cores each, and main node. There are 4 spark jobs running, as I can see in browser, in HUE->jobs, 3 Zeppelin notebooks and one is a python script (pyspark) that I run from command line. The scripts complains with this message:"WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources" for last hour. So my question is: is there a way to see which of running jobs consumes what resources (cores, RAM) ? What tools can I use for this purpose?
I run linux "htop" command on main node, which of course shows a lot of cores available and lots of unused RAM, but I need a tool to see load on nodes.
I found a link to SparkUI from Zeppelin notebook, which shows only Zeppelin-related jobs, but not all (command line jobs are not there, Jupyter notebook neither, etc).
HUE shows a list of all jobs running, but there is no way to see the resource load that each job creates.
Is there a tool that shows this information?

Comment: Yarn Resource Manager UI shows which application is consuming what resources. That's your one stop shop for all Yarn applications. Also, Ganglia for overall consumption.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like Yarn UI port 8088 was not allowed. Now when I opened it, Yarn UI is available and has some useful info!